Is there a way to use the environment variable the Azure static web app provides for the Vue App?
Is there a way to use the environment variable the Azure static web app provides for the Vue App?
what is the best approach to deploy a vue app to Azure static web app and make use of [![enter image description here][1]][1]the environment variable?
want to make use of the environment variable shown below.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/AhQkLw8J.png

Can you provide more details, such as the code you're using and the specific error you're receiving related to environment variables?

I have created a Dummy VueJs App for the POC purpose of using the environment variable of Azure static web app.
It is taking the value from the env file but when I try to make use of the environment variable it is not picking the value instead showing an empty string.
I am using the approach shown here but still no luck
https://chatgpt.com/share/66ff7146-1464-8003-ab1b-6b320cad79ae.
In simple words, I just wanted to see is there any way we can use environment variable of the static web app. @AsleshaKantamsetti

It's unknown what your project looks like. Does it use Vue CLI to build? Because VUE_APP_ prefix presumes that and cannot work in other cases


Is there a way to use the environment variable the Azure static web app provides for the Vue App?

I created a simple Vue.js app and fetched the environment variables after deploying it to Azure Static Web Apps.
I pushed my .env file to GitHub repository and fetch the environment variables from .env file
Below is the complete code used to fetch the environment variables.
HelloWorld.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Environment Variables</h1>
    <p><strong>License API OCP Key:</strong> {{ licenseApiKey }}</p>
    <p><strong>License API URL:</strong> {{ licenseApiUrl }}</p>
    <p><strong>Transfer Admin API URL:</strong> {{ transferAdminApiUrl }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      licenseApiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_LICENSE_API_OCP_KEY,
      licenseApiUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_LICENSE_API_URL,
      transferAdminApiUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_TRANSFER_ADMIN_MI_API_URL
    };
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>

Below is my environment variables.
.env:
VUE_APP_LICENSE_API_OCP_KEY=your-license-api-key-here
VUE_APP_LICENSE_API_URL=<VueApiLicenseApiUrl>
VUE_APP_TRANSFER_ADMIN_MI_API_URL=<VueAppTransferAdminMiApiUrl>

The following GitHub workflow was used to deploy a Vue.js app to an Azure Static Web App.
Workflow File:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_PLANT_001EFD010 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "dist" 
  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_PLANT_001EFD010 }}
          action: "close"

Azure Static Web App Output:


@nirav shah Is your issue resolved, let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
